# Finishing proof of tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a problem where I need to prove that $[(p → q) ∧ (q → r)] → (p → r)$ is a tautology. I've gotten through some of it, but haven't completed it. I think I may be doing something wrong when it comes to dropping parenthesis. Any help would be appreciated! Here is what I have so far:
$[(p → q) ∧ (q → r)] → (p → r)$
$≡ ¬[(p → q) ∧ (q → r)] ∨ (p → r)$
$≡ ¬(p → q) ∧ ¬(q → r) ∨ (p → r)$
$≡ ¬(¬p ∨ q) ∧ ¬(¬q ∨ r) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)$
$≡ p ∨ ¬q ∧ q ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬p ∨ r$

At this point I'm not sure what to do with it. I'm not sure what ways I can re-arrange it so that it will evaluate to True. Or maybe I have done it incorrectly. Thanks to anyone who can correct me or give any advice.

Comment: A truth table with 8 rows would knock this out quickly.

Comment: Or a [theorem-proving automaton](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2424487/328173) ;)

Comment: @Randall I would! However, I'm trying to solve it without in preparation for a test.

Comment: In line 3 you applied DeMorgan's without switching your and to an or.

Comment: @N.Thompson  so what are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you made a mistake.

"Not (A and B)" corresponds to "not A" **or** "not B". In your third line, there is an error.

This is sometimes called [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: That helped, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can FAIL to be a tautology is when your main antecedent is true and $p \to r$ is false.  The latter forces $p$ true and $r$ false.  $q$ is the only variable here.

But remember, we need your original antecedent to be true.  If $q$ is true then $q \to r$ is now false so your antecedent is false.  Similarly if $q$ is false then $p \to q$ is false and again your antecedent is false.

Hence it cannot fail to be a tautology, so it is.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}
\ [(p \to q) \land (q \to r)] \to (p \to r) &\equiv [(\lnot p \lor q)\land (\lnot q \lor r)] \to (\lnot p \lor r) \\
&\equiv \lnot[(\lnot p \lor q)\land (\lnot q \lor r)] \lor (\lnot p \lor r) \\
&\equiv [\lnot(\lnot p \lor q)\lor \lnot(\lnot q \lor r)] \lor (\lnot p \lor r) \\
&\equiv [( p \land \lnot q)\lor (q \land \lnot r)] \lor (\lnot p \lor r) \\
&\equiv \{[( p \land \lnot q)\lor q] \land [(( p \land \lnot q)\lor\lnot r)]\} \lor (\lnot p \lor r) \\
&\equiv \{[( p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor q)] \land [ (p\lor\lnot r) \land (\lnot q \lor\lnot r)]\} \lor (\lnot p \lor r) \\
&\equiv \{[( p \lor q) \land T] \land [ (p\lor\lnot r) \land (\lnot q \lor\lnot r)]\} \lor (\lnot p \lor r) \\
&\equiv [( p \lor q)\lor (\lnot p \lor r)] \land [T\lor (\lnot p \lor r)] \land  [(p\lor\lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)] \\
& \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \land [(\lnot q \lor\lnot r)\lor (\lnot p \lor r)] \\
&\equiv T \land T \land  T \land T \\
&\equiv T
\end{array}$